# C++/CX Header file can't find Microsoft namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2013, directx-11, c++-cx

I have a header file with the following code:

```
  Microsoft::WRL:ComPtr<ID3D11Device2> m_device;
```

inside a class definition. Visual Studio 2013 is saying that Microsoft is not a namespace, if I take the code and cut it out and put it in another class in another file unchanged it works just fine!

Any ideas?

Philip

EDIT: All of a sudden (without me having changed anything) Intelissense now accepts Microsoft::WRL::ComPtry as valid but when I compile it still gives me errors that it does not exists.

Comment: Are you including `client.h` to let the compiler know about the `ComPtr` type and the namespace? Maybe the other file already includes it or includes something that includes it.

Comment: A file with the name client.h does not show up in auto complete. Also the other file I went pasted in to test does not include anything else and it works...

Comment: The point of using C++/CX is that you don't have to fall back to the voodoo lower layers, the kind where dragons live.  You invoke the dragon with `#include <wrl\client.h>` so the compiler can see the namespace and type.  Which helps it find c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt\wrl\client.h if the Sun is shining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to

```
#include <wrl.h>
```

or

```
#include <wrl/client.h>
```

To get `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` in your module.

When you say "Visual Studio 2013 is saying that Microsoft is not a namespace" do you mean you get a compiler error or is just Intellisense? When dealing with headers, Intellisense can get a bit out of sync until you build again. For example:

```
//Test.h
class A { Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<T> a; };

//Test.cpp
#include <wrl/client.h>
#include "Test.h"
```

If you just added the `#include <wrl/client.h>` to the Test.cpp, Intellisense might not know yet it is in scope for the header. It's perfectly valid C++ already, but a better practice is to include in your headers the ones it needs like:

```
//Test.h
#pragma once
#include <wrl/client.h>
class A { Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<T> a; };
```

The other way this sync issue can manifest itself is if you are doing:

```
//Test.h
class A { Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<T> a; };

//Test.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "Test.h"

//pch.h
#include <wrl/client.h>
```

Again, fully valid C++ that will build. Intellisense knows it works when you build, but might not until then.

**Note: WRL is traditional C++ and is not using C++/CX language extensions.** They both exist to make it easier to consume WinRT APIs from C++, and you will see the `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` used inside C++/CX applications when dealing with non-WinRT COM APIs like Direct3D. And you can mix C++/CX with WRL in the same application taking advantage of the fact that you can use `reinterpret_cast<>` between C++/CX ref ^ and ABI COM pointers. You can use `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` in old-school Windows desktop apps on Windows 7 or Windows Vista too.

*With all that said, WRL and C++/CX are two distinct things.*

**Update:** For consuming Windows Runtime APIs, you can also use C++/WinRT which is also 'standard' C++ without any need for the C++/CX extensions. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/). You can use `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` for C++/WinRT applications, or you can use their variant `wrl::com_ptr`